# How to get a mentioned user's id from a message | Discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord.js

So I am trying to implement a warn function to my discord.js bot and I want to get a userID from a mentioned user. I have tried `message.user.id`, `message.mentions.users.first().id` and `message.mentions[0].id` with no avail.

All of them returning `TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined`

How do I do this properly?

(Edit)
I forgot to say that i want to send a DM to the mentioned user.

Comment: `msg.mentions.users.first().id` works for me. It'll only give me that error if there wasn't actually a mention in the message. Try doing a quick `console.log(message.content)`. Are you sure that your bot is looking at the right message?

Comment: please provide more infor how message look like. `message.mentions.users.first().id` just work when in message your mentions someone.

Comment: The message was:
st!warn <@userID here> testing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because there were no mentions in the message, you could essentially use an if statement (or ternary operator) to fix this issue here

```
const user = message.mentions.users.first();
if (!user) return console.log('no user found');
const userID = user.id;
```

You could also use a regex so that you can use both user ID's as well as the mentions

```
const user = await message.client.users.fetch(/\D/g, '').catch(() => {});
if (!user) return console.log('no user found oof');
const userID = user.id;
```

The regex `/\D/g` removes all non digit characters, since a mention is made up like this in discord `<@ID>` the regex would remove `<@>` and match the ID with all available users in discord and return the promise, hence await is used. (if no user is found it would return false)

Comment: This works, so i will mark it as an answer. Many thanks!

Comment: @stationaryStation np

Answer (score 1):

message.mentions.users returns a Collection, if there are no mentions or if the mentioned user is not cached the Collection may be empty, another way you can try is to use a regex on the message's content

```
const id = message.content.match(/<?@?!?(\d{17,19})>?/)[1]
```

The regex matches <@id> or plain id and gives the id as the match